# MVC jQuery sorting images (Drag Drop)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

in the view i have

```
<div class="ui-sortable Imgsel">
    <ul class="list-group" id="SortableGallery" style="cursor:move">
    
    </ul>
       
</div>
```

the for thee **"SortableGallery"** there is a function that adds the image on button press with this Ajax

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
$('<li class="list-group-item col-md-4"><div><img id="image_' + i + '" src="' + '/TempUPL_FLD/' + '@Model.ImageURL' + '/' + i + '.' + ext + '" class="img-responsive MvImgUpl"/></div></li>').appendTo($("#SortableGallery"));
                                }
```

then the script

```
<script>
    $("#SortableGallery").sortable({

        update: function () {

            alert("Wow");
        }
    });
</script>
```

[!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUUF7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUUF7.png)
i get the Cannot move image icon... ?

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the `li` have been added to the `ul` before `$("#SortableGallery").sortable(` is executed

Comment: no the <li> items are added upon image upload button press, so it will be after ?

Answer (score 0):

okey, fixed it my **jquery-ui** was not loading propperyl

done a test

```
if (window.jQuery) {
        if (window.jQuery.ui) {
            alert("jqueryIO loaded");
        } else {
            alert("jquery-ui isn't loaded");
        }
    } else {
        alert("jquery is NOT loaded");
    }
```